# How to select an item from a column only if none of the value in corresponding column is NULL

Tags: sql-server

I want to know if I can assemble a part.( Which is possible if I have all the raw material). So from the Table I want to select the item number only if Quantity for raw material is NOT NULL (not zero).

The table is like this
[image]

So I want the result AS

```
Model 2
Model 3
Model 4
```

The query I am using is

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemNumber FROM TABLE WHERE QUANTITY IS NOT NULL
```

But because in 2 rows Model 1 have some quantity which is not NULL I am getting that in result as well.
Please let me know a way of fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use NOT IN and a subselect

> ```
> CREATE TABLE modelitem
>     ([ltemNumber] varchar(7), [Cornponent] varchar(6), [Quantity] varchar(4))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO modelitem
>     ([ltemNumber], [Cornponent], [Quantity])
> VALUES
>     ('Modell', 'Wheel', '19'),
>     ('Modell', 'Bolt', '19'),
>     ('Modell', 'Engine', NULL)
>     ,('Modell', 'Engine', NULL),
>     ('Model 2', 'Wheel', '19'),
>     ('Model 2', 'Bolt', '19'),
>     ('Model 2', 'Engine', '6'),
>     ('Model 3', 'Wheel', '19'),
>     ('Model 3', 'Bolt', '19'),
>     ('Model 3', 'Engine', '6'),
>     ('Mode14', 'Wheel', '19'),
>     ('Mode14', 'Bolt', '19'),
>     ('Mode14', 'Engine', '6')
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT [ltemNumber] FROM modelitem WHERE [ltemNumber] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [ltemNumber] FROM modelitem WHERE [Quantity] IS NULL)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | ltemNumber |
> | :--------- |
> | Mode14     |
> | Model 2    |
> | Model 3    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7c9b7cd7a9d96e97587d354c8e75d7f7)*

Comment: What if there are two rows for a model that are null - sure it works but effetively it's doing `NOT IN ('Model14', 'Model14')

Comment: you are right i added the DISTINCT

Comment: The inner `DISTINCT` is completely pointless, and there is really no need for a self-join

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ltemNumber] FROM modelitem
EXCEPT
SELECT [ltemNumber] FROM modelitem
WHERE [Quantity] IS NULL
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @modelitem TABLE ([ltemNumber] VARCHAR(7), 
                          [Cornponent] VARCHAR(6), 
                          [Quantity] VARCHAR(4));

INSERT INTO @modelitem ([ltemNumber], [Cornponent], [Quantity])
VALUES ('Model1', 'Wheel', '19'), 
       ('Model1', 'Bolt', '19'), 
       ('Model1', 'Engine', NULL), 
       ('Model1', 'Engine', NULL), 
       ('Model 2', 'Wheel', '19'), 
       ('Model 2', 'Bolt', '19'), 
       ('Model 2', 'Engine', '6'), 
       ('Model 3', 'Wheel', '19'), 
       ('Model 3', 'Bolt', '19'), 
       ('Model 3', 'Engine', '6'), 
       ('Mode14', 'Wheel', '19'), 
       ('Mode14', 'Bolt', '19'), 
       ('Mode14', 'Engine', '6')

SELECT [ltemNumber]
  FROM @modelitem
 GROUP BY [ltemNumber]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN quantity IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: ... is the correct way to do it. No need for an inefficient self-join. Although not sure why you need the `order by`

Comment: @Charlieface , I added it to check the results no need of 'ORDER BY'